# Chef times out syncing cookbooks in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, knife, chef-infra

Following the getting started tutorial here:

https://learnchef.opscode.com/starter-use-cases/multi-node-ec2/

Chef fails trying to sync cookbooks when I try to use an ubuntu 13 AMI.

The knife command is as follows:

```
knife ec2 server create --availability-zone us-east-1d --node-name redis.learnchef.demo --flavor t1.micro --image ami-ad184ac4 --identity-file ~/.ssh/my.pem --run-list 'role[redis]' --ssh-user ubuntu --security-group salt-dev

Error Syncing Cookbooks:
Error connecting to https://s3-external-1.amazonaws.com/opscode-platform-production-data/organization-... - Connection timed out - connect(2)
Your chef_server_url may be misconfigured, or the network could be down.
Relevant Config Settings:
chef_server_url  "https://api.opscode.com/organizations/xx-chef"
```

I'm new to Chef and having a hell of a time getting anywhere useful with it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Looks like a misconfigured chef workstation. Test that your connection to chef is working by running the command "knife client list".

Comment: knife client list
    xx-chef-validator
    xxxxxxx-starter
    memcached.learnchef.demo
    redis.learnchef.demo

Comment: Is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 0):

That error is coming back from AWS's S3, not Chef. I believe AWS might have had an outage during that time. Is this still an issue for you?

If this is still an issue, can you please post your full `knife.rb` and the entire stack trace you see when running the command?